# How to stop original list from updating when cloned list is updated

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I want to stop `self.lineDetails` from being updated when I update `self.modifiedLineDetails`.

```
self.modifiedLineDetails = [];
angular.forEach(self.lineDetails, function (value1, index1) {
    var lineDetail = self.lineDetails[index1];
    self.modifiedLineDetails.push(lineDetail)
});
console.log(self.lineDetails)
angular.forEach(self.modifiedLineDetails, function (value10, index10) {
    var modifiedLineDetail = self.modifiedLineDetails[index10];
    if (modifiedLineDetail.SelectedCustomers.length > 0) {
        modifiedLineDetail.SelectedCustomers = 1;
    } else {
        modifiedLineDetail.SelectedCustomers = 0
    }
});
console.log(self.modifiedLineDetails)
```

Previously I just assigned it like this `self.modifiedLineDetails = self.lineDetails` then I updated `self.modifiedLineDetails` but it wasn't working so I tried pushing it per line but `self.lineDetails` keeps updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem seems to be occurring because I was using `angular`. I researched and found `angular.copy` which creates a [deep copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy). The code below worked for me.

```
self.modifiedLineDetails = angular.copy(self.lineDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clone an array and then modify your new array, one way to do this is using 
spread operation [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Here is the example of it:

```js
var initialarray = [1,2,3,4];
var modification = [...initialarray];
modification.push(5);
console.log(initialarray);
console.log(modification);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work maybe it's because I'm using angularjs

Comment: I cloned it like this self.modifiedLineDetails = [...self.lineDetails]; then I modified it using angular.forEach

Comment: what console says after you modified?

Comment: self.modifiedLineDetails was modified but self.lineDetails was also modified.

Comment: @klent can you please edit your question and update the code you modified?

Comment: This can be a problem with your binding too